# Is it bad practice to call a method within itself?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'm creating a short program to find the average of a given set of numbers. This is a program whose basic structure was first worked out with goto statements on a TI-83, so I'm a little unsure on proper practices with this sort of thing. Here's the code in question:

```
$sum     = 0
$counter = 0

def average
  puts "Input another number, or \"end\" to end."
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == "end"
    puts $counter
    puts ($sum / $counter).to_f
  else
    $sum += input.to_f
    $counter += 1
    puts $counter
    average #Here the method is called again, repeating the cycle.
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how else to do this, as the point of the code being built like this is that it can handle an uncertain number of inputs, hence it's repeating nature.

Answer (score 5):

Among the languages that feature so-called "tail-call optimisation", this kind of structure is the primary way of looping. Ruby, however, does not; recursion (re-entering a function that has already been entered) is commonly used, but not as a general replacement for simple looping, as in this case.

Here, as pvg states, a `while` (or, equivalently, `until`) loop is better:

```
sum = 0
counter = 0
puts "Input a number, or \"end\" to end."
input = gets.chomp
until input == "end"
  sum += input.to_f
  counter += 1
  puts "Input another number, or \"end\" to end."
  input = gets.chomp
end
puts sum / counter
```

Or an infinite loop with a `break`:

```
sum = 0
counter = 0
loop do
  puts "Input a number, or \"end\" to end."
  input = gets.chomp
  break if input == "end"
  sum += input.to_f
  counter += 1
end
puts sum / counter
```

But you could also use more Rubyish ways:

```
puts 'Input numbers, or "end" to end.'
array = STDIN.each_line.lazy
  .map(&:chomp)
  .take_while { |line| line != "end" }
  .map(&:to_f)
  .to_a
puts array.inject(&:+) / array.size
```

Or a bit more ugly but memory-efficient:

```
puts 'Input numbers, or "end" to end.'
sum, count = *STDIN.each_line.lazy
  .map(&:chomp)
  .take_while { |line| line != "end" }
  .inject([0, 0]) { |memo, x|
    [memo[0] + x.to_f, memo[1] + 1]
  }
puts sum / count
```

Comment: You probably want to show one answer with a conditional loop that replicates the behaviour of the question's code exactly (and doesn't unnecessarily repeat the input prompt :)  

The 'Rubyish' version is a frightening monster that will keep me from sleeping tonight.

Comment: @pvg: The second version is an unconditional loop that replicates the behaviour of the question's code exactly (and doesn't unnecesarily repeat the input prompt :) Should I have said "functional" instead of "more Rubyish"? :P

Comment: It's a reasonable (if exhaustive!) answer and I'm no expert Rubyist.  I think pedagogically, for someone who is moving from 'control flow in terms of ifs and gotos', the sensible next step is 'pre- and post- conditional loops, chosen so you don't repeat yourself', which is why I'm not that fond of the first example. Unconditional loop with break is more suitable for situations in which the terminating condition can't be easily expressed up front and the functional version is for, well, when you're hardcore.

Comment: This makes sense! Well, the first two do, at least, since I'm not really experienced with Ruby at the moment. I don't know why using loops didn't occur to me, but thank you very much regardless!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a method can call itself. This is called recursion, a very important concept in programming and computer science.

All you need is a base case and the call to itself. In your example, the base case is

```
if input == "end"
    puts $counter
    puts ($sum / $counter).to_f
```

And the recusive step is

```
else
    $sum += input.to_f
    $counter += 1
    puts $counter
    average #Here the method is called again, repeating the cycle.
```

Comment: While it is not bad practice, and it is an important CS concept, it carries practical limitations in Ruby and in this particular case, the user is far better served by a (most likely while) loop.

Comment: @pvg really, how come it's bad in ruby? I don't have any experience in it

Comment: it's not terrible Ruby, it works but every subsequent call creates a new stackframe and eats memory for no reason. This would be true in Python, in Java, in PHP, in C. There are languages such as Scheme that perform 'tail call elimination' which would make this construct as efficient as a loop. But as a practical matter, you want to express this with a loop.

Comment: @pvg If it works the same as in Java, then recursion is a perfectly fine way of doing it. Every subsequent call only creates a new stackframe if you perform head recursion (which can also be performed in Scheme, it's not language specific). Tail-recursion (and iterative recursion) can also be performed in Java as well

Comment: That's actually not the case for most Ruby implementations I'm aware of and most other languages that are not Scheme. You can perform tail recursion but there is no tail recursion elimination.

Comment: @pvg: Actually, MRI *can* do tail-call optimisation, it just isn't enabled by default (and the way to run code with tail-call optimisation switched on is not intuitive at all). I think you can enable it in JRuby too; Rubinius AFAIK still can't do it. But given that the default is "no tail-call optimisation", best to just assume it's not available.

Comment: @Amadan so i think we're in violent agreement there is no reliable, guaranteed default TCE in Ruby. The whole recursion thing is a bit of a sideshow in general, the person asking the question is working their way up from TI-83 BASIC, a wonderfully oldskool way to learn to program.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a new answer, but rather an illustrated example to support @adao7000's answer.

Recursion can be a really powerful tool. One of the best examples is when walking through a nested array or hash. Recursion allows you to define how to extract data once, and then use the same process at each level - without you needing to know how many levels there are.

Here is a simple example:

```
nested_array = [
  'level 1',
  [
    'level 2'
  ],
  [
    [
      'level 3',
      [
        'level 4'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

def print_values(element)

  if element.kind_of? Array
    element.each{|e|  print_values(e)}
  else
    puts element 
  end

end

print_values nested_array
```

Note how the print_values method either prints out the the current value or passes the sub-array back to itself.